# How to create a oval clear color view inside a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

I want to create UIView on top of the current view controller to show as a little popup. But this view has an oval clear color background view to show through a particular button. The image looks like below. The entire view is a grey transparent view, and below there is a clear color view inside it. How to create something like this?

[image: popup view]

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional layer with mask,[image] which will form "clear" area. Here the code of procedure to implement this effect.

```
    - (void) createOverlay
{
    UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    overlayView.alpha = 0.75;
    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:overlayView];
    
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    
    CGFloat offsetX = self.view.frame.size.width / 6.0;
    CGFloat offsetY = self.view.frame.size.height / 8.0;
    CGFloat ovalWidth = self.view.frame.size.width - offsetX * 2.0;
    CGFloat ovalHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - offsetY * 3.0;
    CGRect ovalRect = CGRectMake(offsetX, offsetY, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);

    
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, nil, ovalRect);
    CGPathAddRect(path, nil, CGRectMake(0, 0, overlayView.frame.size.width, overlayView.frame.size.height));
    
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    
    maskLayer.path = path;
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    
    // Release the path since it's not covered by ARC.
    overlayView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    overlayView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    
    UIBezierPath *ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:ovalRect];
    CAShapeLayer *lineLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    lineLayer.path = ovalPath.CGPath;
    lineLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    lineLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    lineLayer.lineWidth = 1;
    lineLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:lineLayer];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.buttonView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.switchView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.timeLabel];
    
    self.timeLabel.text = @"";
}
```

Comment: Nice - I really like this solution. I even like the (off stage) planes and cars!